# The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant) : BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

Crash in inflate of com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
started to come on SOME DEVICES .

Crash log :

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme (ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme (ThemeEnforcement.java:213)
com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme (ThemeEnforcement.java:148)
com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes (ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView. (BottomNavigationView.java:160)
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView. (BottomNavigationView.java:133)
```

Source code:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/navView"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:elevation="8dp"
<.. app:itemIconTint and itemTextColor colors are set >
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Theme :
my app theme is extended by Theme.MaterialComponents.Light . Document (https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes) says that you should use
bridge theme to support material components.
I can't change my base app theme.
is this reason for crash ?

so my question is -

can i define custom theme just for BottomnavigationView which would extend Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge ..

```
 <style name="bottomNav" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge"> </style>
```

like this and use this style in bottomNavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/navView"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/bottomNav"
/>
```

will this fix my issue ? and why?
2. any other approach ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set theme on Application level

```
 <application
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
...
 </application>
```

Comment: Theme.MaterialComponents.Light is eventual child of Theme.AppCompat.Light only , currently my application theme is Theme.MaterialComponents.Light. 
Also can you explain ? why it is coming on some devices only (less than 5 %) ?

Comment: Hmm, do you use AndroidX?

Comment: yeah , using AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

Hopes the following code helps

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/customTheme"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_item_color"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />
```

and add the following to `themes.xml` file

```
<style name="customTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">  
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/heebo_semibold</
 </style>
```

Comment: why should i use ToolbarTheme for BottomNavigationView ??  and why ThemeOverlay ? reason of my asking is that , i am not able to reproduce this ,

Comment: Actually this just a name(ToolbarTheme), you can replace it any name.

Comment: i m using createBadge with bottomnavigation , that would stop working if i move to AppCompat theme , moreover , how this will solve my problem is not clear to me .

Comment: Did you tried this     style="@style/Widget.App.BottomNavigationView"              
                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                              
  <style name="Widget.App.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.BottomNavigationView</item>
</style>